# d3.js Bottom to Top force layout - drag behavior

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I've a bottom to top force tree layout. Somehow the drag behavior doesn't work as per expectation out of the box obviously. I'm not able to find a perfect way to achieve the desired drag behavior. As one can observe, it is currently in inverse direction to the tree.

Block - http://bl.ocks.org/git-ashish/6d5f8014661488ae786b

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ashishsingh/jyrwsa0y/

```
function tick(e) {

// Push sources up and targets down to form a weak tree.
var k = 6 * e.alpha;
json.links.forEach(function(d, i) {
  d.source.y -= k;
  d.target.y += k;
});

node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return h - d.y; });

link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return h - d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return h - d.target.y; });
}
```

Any help or directions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you mean in the comment with "weak tree", but it seems to me like you want to put source down and targets up, not viceversa.

Changing the `tick` function with this:

```
function tick(e) {

var k = 6 * e.alpha;
json.links.forEach(function(d, i) {
  d.source.y += k;
  d.target.y -= k;
});

node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
}
```

You get [this behaviour (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrwsa0y/2/) which is the top-down inverted equivalent of [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1138500), which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did "pushing the nodes" incorrectly in my case.